# Return a incremental group number per group in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I need help to create a query in Access to incrementally number groups of rows, grouped on a common date and keep the "group numbers" increment on the next date like showing in the Result column.

### Date       |ID  |Result

2017/01/09 |809 | 1

2017/01/09 |810 | 1

2017/01/09 |826 | 1

2017/01/10 |826 | 2

2017/01/11 |809 | 3

2017/01/11 |810 | 3

2013/01/11 |826 | 3

2017/01/12 |809 | 4

2017/01/12 |810 | 4

2017/01/12 |826 | 4

Thank you

Comment: Does the source table have an autonumber primary key?  (I see that the `ID` field isn't unique.).  You might have to share more of the source query and table structure.  There could be a tricky way, something like `If(DLookUp("[Date]","tablename","[pID]="&[pID]-1)=[Date],DLookUp("[Result]","tablename","[pID]="&[pID]-1),DLookUp("[Result]","tablename","[pID]="&[pID]-1)+1)` where `pID` is a unique sequential number.  (That's not totally correct; details depend on the rest of the structure that's not included in your question, and also would have to take into account for record zero.)

Comment: It might be easier to add the number to the source table programmatically instead of "temporarily" to a query...  ***or*** to add the column on whatever the *"next step"* is that you're doing with this data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:
`SELECT A.*, (SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM Table1) AS Q1 WHERE A.Date>=[Date]) AS GrpSeq FROM Table1 AS A;`

Another is with properties of textbox in Group Header on report:
RunningSum: OverGroup
ControlSource: =1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which is for exactly the purpose. See in-line comments for typical usage:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

For your case it could be:

```
SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]), False, Format([Date], "yyyymmdd") AS RowID, *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]), False) <> RowCounter("", True));
```